# Save credential in login page with web component

Tags: javascript, authentication, web-component, shadow-dom

I'm trying to build a simple login page with a username and password input and login button but the difference is my inputs and button are web components ([jb-input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jb-input) is what we use).

When the user logs in and redirects the user to his/her dashboard, chrome and Firefox don't ask for saving a credential, probably because our web component using shadow DOM and browser couldn't detect input element with a username and password name attribute.
how can I make it work and make chrome and Firefox or any other password manager detect successful login and save user credentials?

Answer (score 1):

Don't use shadowDOM, so the Browser Tab can access all DOM elements.

Or if you do need shadowDOM, **add** hidden non-shadowDOM inputs in the DOM, your code *inside* the Web Component can read.

shadowDOM are sealed boxes to Password Managers, they can't (or rather won't) access.
No different than using an `<iframe>` for your password form.

Maybe someday they will *dive* into `open` shadowRoots

Answer (score 1):

As Danny has mentioned, your input web-component has to be accessible from the 'document' layer (most likely by avoiding shadowDOM).

You can see [a live working example](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-login/html-examples) of a login form built with web-components based on [Polymer](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/) [here](https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-login/html-examples) (where both username & password for demo is: 'admin') in which the input fields are accessible by browser password managers.
It is also mentioned in the [source code of this example](https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/blob/master/packages/vaadin-login/src/vaadin-login-form.js#L23):

> Component has to be accessible from the `document` layer in order to allow password managers to work properly with form values.

> The component doesn't have a shadowRoot, so the `<form>` and input fields can be styled from a global scope.

One might also find a workaround to this by using [Polymer](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/api/elements/dom-bind)'s feature-rich elements like `dom-bind` or `dom-if` as they allow using Polymer's template features (data binding, declarative event listeners, etc.) in the main document.

Comment: Note that Google side-tracked Polymer and is now developing Lit (which has less Polymer "Framework" style features)